# Newbie in React: how to edit a component that was installed via npm?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I've followed the instructions in this URL (https://github.com/react-component/calendar) to install a component app in my dependencies. I have succesfully installed it, imported it and it is visible and usable in my web app.

```
npm install rc-calendar
import Calendar from 'rc-calendar';
```

```
<Calendar />
```

However, I can't seem to edit it or find a 'Calendar.js' file to make changes to it? I'm able to see it in my package.json file but not more than that

Comment: It'll be somewhere inside your `node_modules` folder. But no, you're not supposed to edit these dependencies. If the component doesn't do what you need then you need to find another, or write your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR You can, but you shouldn't.

When you use npm it's supposed that you don't change those packages, what you can do is create your own version. If you want to find the source code, some packages come with it, you'll find it in: `<project folder>/node_modules/rc-calendar`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find the source files in your node_modules folder in your project.  But I would not edit them there.  If you want to use that plugin as a starting point and edit it from there, I recommend downloading the source files from the github repo and including it in your project as a regular .js file / regular component.  Then you can edit from there.  It looks like that plugin has many files that are written in typescript.

Answer (score 1):

The typical convention is to not edit packages installed via npm . However, you can clone the package repo and include it in your project. There, you can do what ever you want.